# Individual mindset! What are these mindsets called? Where are they all this stored? Who maintains accounts for all beings?

Tags: karma

Each individual has a unique mindset. It's almost impossible to change someone's mind. The same experience creates different impressions. What are these impressions and mindsets called in Sanatana Vocabulary? Where are they stored? Who maintains this account? How can these be altered? Please provide practical answers.